# どうやって数字的に「リクエストが均等的に全てのサーバーに発行されたか」に回答しますか

Tags: r, excel

全てのHTTPサーバーからのアクセスロッグを含むロッグを持っています。３つのサーバーがあり、そのロッグには６０００行含むとします。もし、３つのサーバーへのリクエスト数がいずれも２０００になれば、全てのリクエストがぴったりと均等的にそれらのサーバーに発行されていたと言えますが、それぞれ受け取ったリクエスト数が（5998、1、1）になれば、非常に不均等だと考えられているでしょう。

極端的な例ですが、実際には、直観的に均等かどうか判断できるわけではないですが、或いは、人によって、均等かどうかに関する感覚が違うと思っています。

どのような方法で、数字的（客観的）に「均等かどうか」に回答できますか。T-Test、Z-Test、F-Testはその問題に適用ますか。

Comment: アクセスを均等にしたい理由はなんなのでしょうか？単に数字的にあらわしたいだけなら`Diff <= (Total / ServNum / 100)<1%>`で1%以下であれば均等だと言えますが、
普通サーバ間でアクセスを均等にしたい理由は負荷分散だと思います。アクセス数が均等になるようにではなく、リソースの使用率に対して均等になるべきかと思いました。

Comment: 実はリクエストの振り分けをロードバランサに任せておきました。今、レスポンスタイムの長いリクエストをいくつか見つけましたので、他のサーバーよりも、負荷が高まっているサーバーがあると推測しておきました。アクセスが均等に受け取られなければ、あるサーバーの負荷は高まっていると言えるでしょ、そのため、アクセス数を検測したいです。

Answer (score 2):

> 実はリクエストの振り分けをロードバランサに任せておきました。今、レスポンスタイムの長いリクエストをいくつか見つけましたので、他のサーバーよりも、負荷が高まっているサーバーがあると推測しておきました。

「負荷」をみるために「分散状況」を数学的に考えるのは疑問です。
まずは現実を確認するために、リソース状況を確認してはいかがでしょうか。
　→負荷高くて処理がおくれているのなら、当然リソース状況に変化があってしかるべきですし。
　そもそも、本番運用しているのなら、リソース監視いれているのでしょうが。。

また、サーバーがわで処理の受付、完了を示すログを集めてそれを分析するのも
城跡です。

Answer (score 1):

今回のような観測された頻度分布と理論上の頻度分布が同じかどうかを検定するにはカイ２乗検定（適合度検定）を使用するのが適当かと思います。
WEB上で検索するとカイ２乗検定を使ってサイコロの出目が均等かどうかを検定する例題がたくさん見つかると思いますので、そのまま今回のリクエスト数の検定に適用できるのではないでしょうか。

---

一応Rのタグがついておりましたので。
Rで書くと

```
result <- chisq.test(x=c(2054,1989, 1957), p=c(1/3,1/3,1/3))
```

のようになります